# Equation for no. of unique distributions of k objects, say balls, out of n total, comprised of multiple colors of varying amounts?

Tags: combinatorics

Say you have 4 orange balls, 3 red and 2 blue, and you take 6 at a time. I can manually that there are 9 possible distributions: 4o2r, 4o2b, 4o1r1b; 3o3r, 3o2r1b, 3o1r2b; 2o3r1b, 2o2r2b; 1o3r2b. But is there an equation to calculate this?

Comment: Have a look here
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1622658/combinations-of-colored-balls

Comment: Thank you! That led me to my answer. I searched and searched but couldn't find anything before